# Core Data: trying to get an array of uuid from a relationship but getting "No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'" error

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

If I have an Core Data Order entity with a one to many relationship with OrderProduct (has a quantity attribute) which has a one to many relationship with Product, how can I get an array of Product ID's from the Order?

I have extended the Order and added a way to get an array of OrderProducts:

```
extension Order {
    
    public var wrappedName : String {
        name ?? "Unknown Order name"
    }
    
    public var orderProductArray: [OrderProduct] {
        let set = orderProduct as? Set<OrderProduct> ?? []
        
        return set.sorted {
            $0.product?.wrappedName ?? "" < $1.product?.wrappedName ?? ""
        }
    } 
}
```

which works well for getting a list of OrderProducts from the Order, but I would like to get an array of product id's in the order from the order. I have tried adding this to the extended Product:

```
public var productIdArray: [String] {
    var tempUuids: [String] = []
    
    ForEach (orderProductArray) { op in
        if let tempUuid = op.product?.id?.uuidString {
            tempUuids.append(tempUuid)
        }
    }
    return tempUuids
}
```

but am getting an error:

> No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'

Comment: It is a typo somewhere, comment out sections. I had this error pop up yesterday and it was a property I had changed.

Comment: `ForEach (orderProductArray)`? Did you mean `orderProductArray.forEach {` instead? You aren't in SwiftUI here, you're in "pure" Swift.

Comment: Unrelated but why is everything optional? The *array of product id's in the order from the order* is pointless if one of the `id`s is `nil`. And – as Larme already said – `ForEach` (capitalized) is for SwiftUI views. You can do the same more efficiently with `public var productIdArray: [String] { orderProductArray.compactMap{$0.product?.id?.uuidString}`

Comment: _"OrderProduct ...  has a one to many relationship with Product"_, I assume you mean the opposite that an OrderProduct has one Product and one Product can be used by many OrderProduct?

Comment: @Larme, that's it! I'm new at this but that was super helpful. Can you add that as a response and I will mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ForEach()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach) is for SwiftUI.
It allows you to iterate a random collection (usually an `Array`), and create a view at each iteration.

Here, you're NOT in "SwiftUI", you just want to iterate on that array.

So you need [`forEach()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/foreach(_:)) :

```
ForEach (orderProductArray) { op in
    ...
}
```

->

```
orderProductArray.forEach { op in
    ...
}
```

Side note, you could use `compactMap()` to do so too, according to your code:

```
public var productIdArray: [String] {
    return orderProductArray.compactMap { op in
        guard let tempUuid = op.product?.id?.uuidString else { return nil }
        return tempUuid
    }
}
```

I'll explain why:
You iterate over the array, and for each element you return something different, aka you "transform" each element into another one. So it's a `map()`.
Well, that's almost your code, in fact, you skip some values, so you need to use instead a `compactMap()`. It's the same as a `map()` except that when you return nil, it's the same as skipping the value.

Which can be simplified with:

```
public var productIdArray: [String] {
    return orderProductArray.compactMap { op in
        op.product?.id?.uuidString
    }
}
```

And then into:

```
public var productIdArray: [String] {
   orderProductArray.compactMap { $0.product?.id?.uuidString }
}
```

But keep the version your current Swift level can debug and modify.

Comment: That is perfect! So much cleaner and worked great. I learned a ton from this answer as well. Thank you.